# Get table row ID after dropzone event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dropzone.js

I've been banging my head on this for hours so hopefully someone can help. I'm trying to fetch either the row id or the form id when a file is uploaded into a dropzone box. I have multiple table rows with multiple dropzone boxes.

Here is an example row from my table:

```
<table class="docs" id="show">      
    <tr class="doc" id="*Need_This*">
        <td>
            <div class="file_upload drop">
                <form class="dropzone clickable" id="*Or_Need_This*">
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
        paramName: 'photos',
        url: "post.php",
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drag or Click",
        clickable: true,
        enqueueForUpload: true,
        init: function() {
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            this.on("success", function(file) { alert(id); });
          }
    });
});
</script>
```

Right now it's returning undefined. I need to get the id's so that I can append css changes to other elements on the row. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

`this` in your case refers to the Dropzone instance, not the element itself! If you need to access the actual element of your dropzone, use `dropzone.element`.

So you can do: `var id = $(this.element).etc...`.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation you can read :

> Gets the server response as second argument

Try with this :

```
this.on("success", function(file,rep) {
     alert(file);
     alert(rep); //The response
});
```